# How do I write long running requests in go?

Tags: database, postgresql, go, benchmarking

Story so far. We are thinking about switching away from perl. The candidates are go or node. For that we wrote simple wrappers in Dancer2, Flask, Node and Go for a long running database query that we have. I had them all up and running, so I benchmarked a bit with light load. Then I decided to stress the applications. Every framework was able to cope with

```
ab -n 1000 -c 100 http://localhost:8080/
```

except go. If I did not limit connection then I would get error 'too many connections', if I limited connections to 100, then ab would give timeout error and quit.

My gist https://gist.github.com/2d8473ce576cab5f7c66 with go code. What should I change, so I can use go server under load?

Comment: Your gist is not loading for me.

Comment: Remove the .git suffix to view it online.

Comment: What exactly is giving you the "too many connections" error? Postgres, go,  ab? (and please try something other than ab)

Comment: The "problem" is that go spawns a new goroutine and db connection per incoming request, so you probably blow out the database's incoming connection. You can limit that with something like a worker pool and channels for incoming/outgoing requests, or some sort of barrier that makes sure no more than N requests are being sent to the database at once.

Comment: Agree with Not_a_Golfer: "too many connections" sounds like something from the DB. And it's there for a reason: if running all those long queries is doing real work, then running too many of them is going to starve new queries of resources and make the DB slow to do anything. You might end up having to work out how not to be constantly running many copies of this long query, either by caching it for one user and showing the cached result to others (if applicable) or tuning the SQL.

Comment: The spawning part is correct, as the query is long running and as I understand that every request spawns, then all the resources are consumed. Would a framework like martini etc. solve the problem for me? Being a new gopher, it is hard to work with high powered tool without protection and keep all my mental limbs :D I'm surprised that node is not going berserk.

Answer (score 2):

The trouble looks like you are overloading your database with too many simultaneous connections. Remember Go is a truly concurrent language.

Have you tried setting `db.SetMaxOpenConns(1000)` to a much smaller number, say `db.SetMaxOpenConns(10)`?

Or alternatively you could limit the number of simultaneously running goroutines like this

Declare these globally

```
const maxAtOnce = 50

var limiter = make(chan struct{}, maxAtOnce)

func init() {
    // Fill up with tokens
    for i := 0; i < maxAtOnce; i++ {
        limiter <- struct{}{}
    }
}
```

And in your `getTimeSheet` put this at the start

```
// take a token
<-limiter
// give it back on exit
defer func() {
    limiter <- struct{}{}
}()
```

Comment: Hm, are the other frameworks limiting artificially or have set default values? And if I limit, will it cause benchmark to time out again? Forgot to mention, that the sql query takes 10-20 seconds to run, so it is easy to overload the database and fill the open connections :)

Comment: I suspect that the other frameworks aren't truly concurrent, as in they will be processing some of the requests sequentially.  Your original Go code will definitely make 100 simultaneous connections to the database... As for will it timeout - I don't know - you'll have to experiment.